# What is the difference between "shiver" and "shudder"?

Tags: meaning, word-difference

What is the difference between "shiver" and "shudder"?

Oxford dictionary gives quite similar meaning:

- [shiver](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shiver) - shake slightly and uncontrollably as a result of being cold,
  frightened, or excited
- [shudder](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shudder) - tremble convulsively, typically as a result of fear or revulsion

So seems like both can be used to describe the situation when a person is frightened. Is it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both words can be used to describe when a person is frightened (although, typically, I initially think of *shivering* in the cold, and *shuddering* at a thought).

I also think of shivers lasting a little longer than shudders. I might say, "I was shivering at the bus stop for almost twenty minutes!" but, "When I stepped outside, I shuddered in the cold," referring to a momentary shudder.

Likewise, if a young child trembled in fright during a scary movie, I might say he "shivered through the movie," or "shuddered at a scene." However, I must point out there are no hard rules about this; these are just ways I typically use these two words.

*Shiver* is also used in the expression "Shiver my timbers!" – which I don't hear very often, unless someone is trying to do a humorous imitation of a pirate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both can be used to describe when a person is frightened. The difference between the two is that *shudder* is stronger than *shiver*.

For example, *shiver* could range from, "*It sent a small shiver down his spine*." to, "*It made him shiver all over*:" By comparison, *shudder* is a stronger, more jarring, reaction, "*It made him shudder*."